# syntax error on line 26

Tags: php

Белая страница с такой вот ошибкой:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Q'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/u/uwebma04/direkt/public_html/wp-content/themes/ta-pluton/template-home.php on line 26
```

Вот сам код:

```
  <a href="<?php echo $slide['url']; ?>" class="da-link button"> <?php _e( 'Заказать Яндекс.Директ', 'ta-pluton' ); ?></a>
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Проблема может быть в любой строке в файле, а вылетает на линии 26.Прикрепите pastebin файла

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй экранировать кавычки:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($slide['url'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" class="da-link button"> <?php _e( 'Заказать Яндекс.Директ', 'ta-pluton' ); ?></a>
```

Comment: Вся та же ошибка.